# video frames visibly refresh themselves when playing video clips or youtube on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: nvidia, video, display-resolution, youtube, 4k-monitor

My computer comes with strong hardware: AMD Ryzen 3900X; 64G memory; Navdia RTX 2080 Super. Ubuntu 20.04 was installed.

However when I watch youtube videos or test a 1080p mkv format video, I can observe video flames refreshing at noticeable speed, meaning it's slow! This should never happen considering my hardware!

My guess was that no proper driver installed, but running "ubuntu-drivers devices" seems showing the driver installed.

My monitor support 4K ([ViewSonic XG2700-4K](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01A0ZRQTW)).

Motherboard is: [ASUS AM4 TUF Gaming X570-Plus (Wi-Fi)](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/TUF-GAMING-X570-PLUS-WI-FI/)

**Here are some preliminary diagnosis I performed:**

- **sudo dmidecode -s bios-version** , return: 1407
- **free -h**

> ```
>             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available    
>
> Mem:         62Gi       5.8Gi        33Gi       809Mi        23Gi   55Gi    
> Swap:        2.0Gi      0B           2.0Gi
> ```

- **sysctl vm.swappiness**

> vm.swappiness = 60

[image]

[image]

Anyone know what would be the root course for this issue, or any config we can do in Ubuntu? I was expecting a super performance watching high resolution videos or playing games.

Comment: Show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the make/model of your computer or motherboard. Tell me what version Nvidia driver? Show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `sudo lshw -C memory`. Have you ever run `memtest`? Sorry for all of the questions, but I need to gather info for a better response.

Comment: thanks @heynnema! Please see the revised question with the updated info at your request.

Comment: `ubuntu-drivers devices` seems to show only drivers that are installed, but not which of them is actually used. You may want to check in Settings - Software & Updates which one is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**BIOS**

ASUS AM4 TUF Gaming X570-Plus (Wi-Fi)

You have BIOS 1407.

There's a newer BIOS available, version 2407, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/TUF-GAMING-X570-PLUS-WI-FI/HelpDesk_Download/).

[image]

Note: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**Nvidia**

Nvidia RTX 2080 Super

You have driver 440.

There's a newer driver available, version 450.57, and can be downloaded [here](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/drivers/).

[image]
[image]

Comment: thanks @heynnema! I've upgraded both bios and nvidia driver, now it looks much better, at least didn't see any flickering no more - you answer is gleefully accepted! Still not sure why is that. Is it really a driver version issue? BTW, is there any motherboard drivers? The MB came with a disc but it's more like for Windows installation rather than Linux.

Comment: @J.E.Y Glad it worked out for you. Thanks for the update. The disc that came with the MB is likely for Windows only.